# Insert value into sql table - selected column. Using Parameters like c#

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Hi at now i am programming with Java and wanting to insert some value to specific column choosen. Also, i want to add it in parameter similar with C#:
example:

```
SqlCommand cmdb = new SqlCommand("insert into Assignment1(textname,person,date,text)
    values (@textName,@person,@date,@text)", con);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textname", textPathLabel.Text);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person", personNameTB.Text);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", theBytes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in Java. With the example that you've, the corresponding PreparedStatement would look something like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Assignment1(textname,person,date,text) values(?,?,?,?)");
```

You would then use the appropriate `ps.setXX()` methods to set the appropriate values for the parameters that you've defined and then call `ps.executeUpdate()` to execute the call to the database.

The ["JDBC(TM) Database Access"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) would be a good place to start learning about how to use or execute common SQL statements, and perform other objectives common to database applications.